# Python3 non-utf8 pygeoip module and howto decode

Tags: python, utf-8

I am reading a CSV in Python3 like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pygeoip
import csv

array = []
    with open('ips.log', 'rb') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        for row in spamreader:

            row.append(geo_isp.isp_by_addr(row[1]))
            array.append(row)
```

In my data now I am seeing:

```
['owner': u'AS31334 Kabel Deutschland Vertrieb und Service GmbH', 'ip': '35.91.245.23', 'views': 6]
```

Howto get rid of the `u` in front of the ISP name? Is this the fault of the csv module or the pygeoip module?

I am trying this without success:

`row.append(geo_isp.isp_by_addr(row[1].decode("windows-1252").encode("utf8")))`

This also does still print the 'u' in front of the string:

`row.append(geo_isp.isp_by_addr(str(row[1])))`

Also see: https://github.com/appliedsec/pygeoip/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are opening your file in a bynary mode.
Change to text mode by changing your open statement to

```
with open('filename','r') as csvfile:
```

This should do the trick